# R: grepl select first charachter on a string

Tags: regex, r, dataframe, grepl

I apologize in advance, this might be a repeat question. However, I just spent the two last hours over stackoverflow, and can't seem to find a solution.

I want to use `grepl` to detect rows that begin with a digit, that's what I tried to use but It didn't give me the rigt answer:

```
   grep.numeric=as.data.frame(grepl("^[:digit:]",df_mod$name))
```

I guess that the problem is from the regular expression `"^[:digit:]"`, but I couldn't figure it out.

**UPDATE**

My dataframe looks like this, It's huge, but below is an example:

```
  ID       mark         name
   1       whatever     name product
   2       whatever     10 product
   3       whatever     250 product
   4       another_mark other product
```

I want to detect products which their names begin with a number.

**UPDATE 2**

applying `grep.numeric=grepl("^[[:digit:]]",df_mod$name)` on the example below give me the right answer which is:

```
    grep.numeric
   [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

But, what drive me crazy is when I pply this fuction to my real dataframe:

```
   grep.numeric=grepl("^[[:digit:]]",df_mod[217,]$nom)
```

give me this result:

```
   grep.numeric
   [1] FALSE
```

But actually, what I have is this :

```
   df_mod[217,]$nom
   [1]  100 lipo 30 gélules
```

Please help me.

Comment: Try `^[[:digit:]]` - it must be inside a character class

Comment: I used a Perl-related question as a source duplicate, but it also is related to POSIX character class, thus should be relevant here, too.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I switched `"^[:digit:]"` by `"^[[:digit:]]"` but nothing changed.

Comment: Ok, please add the missing data to repro your issue. What does the data frame look like?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I deleted it because they subtract my score. I didn't like this any more.

Comment: I understand, but you should also take into account that a question must be [asked appropriately](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make it answerable.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I edited my question. If It needs more clarification please mention this to me. Thank you.

Comment: `grepl("^[[:digit:]]", df_mod$name)` gives the correct result on the provided data set. Also, what are you using `as.data.frame` for? What is your desired result?

Comment: Or maybe [`grep("^[[:digit:]]", df_mod$name, value=TRUE)`](https://ideone.com/nmbqT8)? If you need the values, you need to pass that argument with `TRUE`.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I edited my question, please take a look on it. I need a logic output : `TRUE or FALSE`. That's why I used `grepl`

Comment: @David Arenburg I edited my question, please take a look on it. I used `as.data.frame` to visualize my data. It didn't affect the result.

Comment: Can you provide `dput(df_mod[217,]$nom)`?

Comment: `dput(df_mod[217,]$nom)` gives the same result as `dput(df_mod$nom)` which I can't provide beacause my dataframe is very big (~12000 rows). I can provide the output of the example below:   `> dput(df1$name)
structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("10 product", "250 product", 
"name product 10", "other product 20"), class = "factor")`
   `> dput(df1[1,]$name)
structure(3L, .Label = c("10 product", "250 product", "name product 10", "other product 20"), class = "factor")`

Comment: Ok, does `dput(factor(df_mod[217,]$nom))` gives you smaller result?

Comment: Yes, thank you, here's the output: `dput(factor(df_mod[217,]$nom))
structure(1L, .Label = " 100 lipo 30 gélules", class = "factor")`

Comment: You have leading spaces in your vector, try maybe `grepl("^[[:digit:]]", trimws(df_mod$name))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg , It works!!!! You're such a genius: `grepl("^[[:digit:]]", trimws(df_mod[217,]$nom))
[1] TRUE`. Thank you so much. Can you please switch your comment to an answer, so that other users can take profit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, some of your values have leading spaces, so you could either modify your regex to (or something similar)

```
grepl("^\\s*[[:digit:]]", df_mod$name)
```

Or use the built in `trimws` function

```
grepl("^[[:digit:]]", trimws(df_mod$name))
```

Comment: Yes, the leading spaces in the values caused the problem.
`grepl("^[[:digit:]]", trimws(df_mod$name))` worked like a charm, thank you.

Comment: Did you also try `grepl("^\\s*[[:digit:]]", df_mod$name)`? I like it better.

Comment: Yes, It works also!! I have two solutions for my problem now :)